# Mouse Wheel doesn't work

Tags: 17.04, mouse-scroll

My wireless Mircosoft Mouse Mouse Wheel gets not recognized by the System. 
I tried xev for checking if its just a setting-problem, but there happing nothing either... Clicking with it works, but scrolling not.
I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome and Unity 7, but had the same Problem also at 16.10

Comment: Sorry to disturb, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170993/mouse-wheel-doesnt-scroll-after-update) worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Answer (score -1):

I just solved this problem on Ubuntu 18.04 with doing Natural Scrolling on and off again. Path is Settings>Devices>Mouse&Touchpad>Natural Scrolling.