# Mouse wheel doesn't scroll after update

Tags: 18.04, mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I have Ubuntu 18.04. Today in the morning I allowed the updates were installed and after system requested reboot mouse wheel doesn't scroll content up and down anymore. Touchpad still does but it's not convenient for me.
Mouse A4tech laser Model: X6-22D which is connected to the laptop Asus UX310U by wire.
Any ideas? Can I fix it or roll back mouse driver update.

Comment: Could you please provide the brand and model of your mouse ? Is it connected by wire, Bluetooth or anything else like Logitech Unifying Receiver ?

Comment: Mouse A4tech laser Model: X6-22D which is connected to the laptop Asus  UX310U by wire.

Comment: To help others, what does your kernel version report using `uname -r` command?

Comment: output : 4.15.0-60-generic that was installed today

Answer (score 1):

I did not find another progressive solution yet and kernel version 5.0.0-27 solved my mouse scrolling problem (until now without any side effects).

I have an A4Tech X6-80D mouse and the 4.15.0-62 kernel contained this bug, so I installed kernel 5.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with the commands below (kernel 5.0 is not automatically installed if you have initially an Ubuntu version lower than 18.04.2).

- Desktop edition:

  ```
  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
  ```
- I did not try the Server edition, for which `xorg` is not needed:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
  ```

Original source to install kernel 5.0 can be found via [How to Get Linux Kernel 5.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-hwe-kernel/).

Answer (score 0):

Boot with your previous kernel version by selecting **Advanced options for Ubuntu** off the grub menu. For more details (or if grub doesn't appear) see:

- [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: I'll do it for sure but later on, once I'll finish critical work.

Comment: Don't hold your breath though: it may be due to Xorg mouse driver rather than the kernel. It actually seems to be more likely.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the problem described above on my Dell Laptop with Ubuntu 18.04: after updating, my A4Tech X6-60MD mouse wheel is not scrolling content anywhere.

After updating the kernel to version 5.0 by running:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

The problem has disappeared.

Answer (score -2):

> please check the mouse setting

In the Mouse Properties window, select the Wheel tab and try adjusting the number of lines to scroll the mouse or try changing the mouse to scroll one page at a time. After this is adjusted, click Apply and then click OK. Verify this change helps correct your mouse issues.

**Please check Instruction in the given image**

[image]

Comment: Sounds promising but neither on your picture nor in my settings I see no Wheel tab. I just can adjust the Mouse speed and it works properly. So, I couldn't find page scrolling or lines scrolling number and sure there is no Apply button in the mouse settings. May be I need to click somewhere to get this wheel tab?

Comment: So, guys thanks a lot all of you. Seems I got to the bottom of that mysterious issue but not as deep as I wanted to since I have no time for debugging.
So, I connected another mouse and it works properly. Seems some chips aren't supported anymore by new driver.

Comment: Best of luck for your future.