# Logitech Mouse Stopped Working Properly

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, logitech-unifying

I am using a Logitech MX Vertical Advance mouse and a Logitech wireless keyboard, each using it's own receiver (dongle). Both receivers are plugged in to a USB switch which is connected to my laptops: 1 Ubuntu (18.04.5 LTS) and 1 Windows (Win10). Everything was working perfectly on both laptops (absolutely **no problems** here).

Yesterday, using the *Logitech Unifying Software* (Win10 machine), I paired both mouse and keyboard to one receiver. Somehow this broke the mouse usage in the Ubuntu machine: wheel, middle button, back/forward buttons no longer work (BTW mouse motion and left/right buttons do work). This strange behavior is only seen in the Ubuntu machine. In the Win10 machine everything works perfectly.

Most solutions to this problem that I found online are: turning mouse OFF/ON or unplugging/plugging back in the receiver. If I do either of those things the mouse is **fully functional** again (wheel, etc.) in the Ubuntu machine. However, as I am using a USB switch to go from one laptop to the other, this temporary "fix" is not a long-term solution for me. For example, I turn mouse OFF/ON and it is fully functional in Ubuntu machine, then switch to Win10 machine and mouse is still fully functional, then switch back to Ubuntu machine but wheel/other buttons no longer work.

I've tried:

1. Unpaired receiver. Basically going back to using 2 receivers (as it was originally). Same behavior.
2. Using another USB switch (different brand). Same behavior, so this is not the problem.
3. Using a different USB port in the Ubuntu laptop. Same behavior.
4. Install Linux kernel 5 but didn't fix the problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1173645/1425490

FYI:

- When the mouse is not fully working, `xev` doesn't recognize scrolling the wheel. After turning mouse OFF/ON, then `xev` does recognize everything.
- Mouse is fully charged.
- I've rebooted the Ubuntu laptop several times.

I'd like to go back to the behavior before yesterday, where mouse was fully functional on both laptops. Is it possible to uninstall mouse drivers and try installing them again? I didn't do this manually, the first time I plugged in the receiver it was probably done automatically. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: This is probably a question for Logitech support since we can't know how the device works and especially not how the Windows software works, but it sounds like the Windows software made a change to the firmware of one or both devices which requires the devices to use the Logitech software to communicate on the single dongle. If Logitech only writes this software for Windows, then it would seem likely that you won't be able to use the devices on Ubuntu with that change to firmware. Again you should probably contact Logitech support/documentation but this is my guess.

Comment: Hi @Nmath thank you for reading and replying to my post. You are probably right about the firmware. I did contact Logitech support but they are no help on Ubuntu, even tough their website says "*supported on most popular Linux distributions*" for the Unifying USB receiver. It was a waste of time contacting them.

Comment: Any Logitech configuration done in Windows should carry over to Ubuntu. The Unifying receiver must be plugged directly into a computer USB port. If you're switching the mouse between two computers using a USB switch... either make sure it's a powered USB device... or don't do it that way. Install `Solaar` in Ubuntu for some configuration capabilities.